# What does waitForAllLinks mean and is there any webdriver's alternative?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

I am having trouble finding the description of what exactly waitForAllLinks action does.
Selenium core reference doesn't say much on the subject unfortunately.

Take this for example:

```
<tr>
        <td>open</td>
        <td>http://www.google.com/</td>
        <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td>sendKeys</td>
        <td>id=gbqfq</td>
        <td>testing</td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td>waitForAllLinks</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10000</td>
</tr>
```

What exactly is being waited for there?

And on a related note, is there any WebDriver alternative for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging through the IDE source code and the selenium reference, waitForAllLinks 
seems to do the following: it tries repeatedly to get all links one the page until the list of retrieved IDs matches the supplied pattern.

The above example from the internet seems to be erroneous. waitForAllLinks accepts only first parameter - a pattern to match. Second argument is ignored. Hence that 10000 in the example is just ignored and waitForAllLinks will be successful only if page contains NO links.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used this command, but in Selenium IDE when you enter any command, at the bottom of the tool there is a Reference tab. For `waitForAllLinks` this tab says:

> waitForAllLinks(pattern)
>
> Generated from getAllLinks()
>
> ```
> Returns:
>     the IDs of all links on the page
>
> Returns the IDs of all links on the page.
>
> If a given link has no ID, it will appear as "" in this array.
> ```

You can look up `getAllLinks()` in [the API](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/index.html?com/thoughtworks/selenium/webdriven/commands/GetAllLinks.html). It is an entire class, but I am afraid the API documentation is not terribly useful.

Hopefully this is enough to get you started.